# Python Multiple inheritance not printing result as expected

Tags: python, diamond-problem

I have a code something like below. I was trying to test multiple-inheritance behaviour of python. I have a base class called Base and D1 and D2 is derived from base when D3 is derived from D1,D2.
I Initialize D2 first and D1 from D3. I initialized D3 with val= 1 , D2 with D3.val+2 and D1 with D3.val+4 . But when I printed init values of all classes, I have noticed that D1 is being initialized with 3 temporarilly.

`

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self,val):
        print ("Base __init__",val)
        self.b_data = val
    def whoami(self):
        print ("I am Base")
    def val(self):
        print ("val of Base",self.b_data)

    def __del__(self):
        print ("Deleting Base")

  class D1(Base):

    def __init__(self,val):
        print ("D1 __init__",val)
        self.d1_data = val 
        super().__init__(self.d1_data)

    def whoami(self):
        print ("I am D1")
    def __del__(self):
        print ("Deleting D1")



class D2(Base):

    def __init__(self,val):
        print ("D2 __init__",val)
        self.d2_data = val +2
        super().__init__(self.d2_data)

    def whoami(self):
        print ("I am D2")
    def __del__(self):
        print ("Deleting D2")


class D3(D2,D1):

    def __init__(self,val):
        print ("D3 __init__",val)
        self.d3_data = val 

        super().__init__(self.d3_data) #callig D2 init
        super(D2,self).__init__(self.d3_data+4) #calling D1 init        
        #D2.__init__(self,100)

    def __del__(self):
        print ("Deleting D3")

if( __name__ == "__main__"):
    objD3 = D3(1)
    print ((objD3.__class__.__mro__))
    objD3.val()
    objD3.whoami()
`
```

But when I run it it shows me result as

```
D3 __init__ 1
D2 __init__ 1
D1 __init__ 3
Base __init__ 3
D1 __init__ 5
Base __init__ 5
(<class '__main__.D3'>, <class '__main__.D2'>, <class '__main__.D1'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>)
val of Base 5
I am D2
Deleting D3
```

Can you please help me understand why at the 3rd line  `D1 __ init__ 3` is getting printed, When I am not initializing D1 with the value 3?

Answer (score 0):

`super` may not be what you expect. Python has a concept of Method Resolution Order, and if you control what it is for `D3` with `print(D3.__mro__)`, you will find:

```
(<class '__main__.D3'>, <class '__main__.D2'>, <class '__main__.D1'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>)
```

When `super()` is used in `D2.__init__` for a `D3` object, it will return a proxy to the next class in `self.__class__.__mro__` which is `D1` and not `Base`. And, because of that, it will call `D1.__init__(3)`.